# php / MySQL - How to join product table together

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

How can I join this table together into 3 sections? One for starters, mains and desserts.

Here is my code so far:

```
<?php

session_start();

$page = 'index.php';

mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('cart') or die(mysql_error());

if (isset($_GET['add'])) {
    $quantity = mysql_query('SELECT id, quantity FROM products WHERE id='.mysql_real_escape_string((int)$_GET['add']));
    while ($quantity_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($quantity)) {
        if ($quantity_row['quantity']!=$_SESSION['cart_'.(int)$_GET['add']]) {
        $_SESSION['cart_' . (int)$_GET['add']] +='1';
        header('Location: ' . $page);

    }
}
header('Location: ' . $page);

}

if (isset($_GET['remove'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart_'.(int)$_GET['remove']]--;
    header ('Location: ' . $page);

}

if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart_' . (int)$_GET['delete']]='0';
    header ('Location: ' . $page);
}



function products() {
    $get = mysql_query('SELECT id, name, description, price FROM products WHERE quantity > 0 ORDER BY id DESC');
    if (mysql_num_rows($get) == 0) {
        echo "There are no products to display.";
    }
    else {

    while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {?>
        <center>
        <table border=2 width=90% cellspacing=5 cellpadding=10 bgcolor=cyan cols=2>
        <th>View</th>
        <th>Dish</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Item Price</th>
        <tr>
        <td>    
        <a href="ice.png"</a>
        </td>
        <td>
        <?echo '<p>'.$get_row['name']?>
        </td>
        <td>
        <?echo $get_row['description']?>
        </td>
        <td>
        <?echo '&pound'.number_format($get_row['price'],2).'<br><br> <a href="cart.php?add='.$get_row['id'].'">Add</a></p>';?>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table></center>

    <?} 

}


}
```

This currently displays:

[image]

But ideally I would not like the headings for each for the items!

Comment: isn't it simply HTML ? (instead of all these tags) ?

Answer (score 1):

You call `table and table header` in while loop. so, that output for this reason.  Try this change

```
function products() {
    $get = mysql_query('SELECT id, name, description, price FROM products WHERE quantity > 0 ORDER BY id DESC');
    if (mysql_num_rows($get) == 0) {
        echo "There are no products to display.";
    }
    else {
        echo "<center>\n";
        echo "  <table border=2 width=90% cellspacing=5 cellpadding=10 bgcolor=cyan cols=2>\n";
        echo "      <tr>\n";
        echo "      <th>View</th>\n";
        echo "      <th>Dish</th>\n";
        echo "      <th>Description</th>\n";
        echo "      <th>Item Price</th>\n";
        echo "      </tr>\n";
        while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {

        ?>
        <tr>
            <td>     <a href="ice.png"</a> </td>
            <td> <?echo '<p>'.$get_row['name']?> </td>
            <td> <?echo $get_row['description']?> </td>
            <td> <?echo '&pound'.number_format($get_row['price'],2).'<br><br> <a href="cart.php?add='.$get_row['id'].'">Add</a></p>';?> </td>
        </tr>
        <?
        } 
        echo "</table>\n";
        echo "</center>\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot this works great! Do you know how I could use a seperate image for each item?

Comment: where will come Img src? if according to product, then `<td>     <a href="ice.png"</a> </td>` change to `<td>     <a href="ice.png"> <img src="<?php echo  $get_row['img_src'] ?>" /></a> </td>`

Comment: hmm this seems to show it on all items still and when I click it displays image :( Can you help me fix this?

Comment: At first keep `display hidden` . when you click then `display show` by css & jquery. Try to get help `css & jquery` by googling..

Comment: No i would just like it to display once next to the appropriate item, I dont want to be able to click it

Comment: updated with screenshot of what i see once implementing your code

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
?> 
<center>
<table border=2 width=90% cellspacing=5 cellpadding=10 bgcolor=cyan cols=2>
<tr>
<th>View</th>
<th>Dish</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Item Price</th> 
<tr>
<?
while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {?>
    <tr>
    <td>    
    <a href="ice.png"</a>
    </td>
    <td>
    <?echo '<p>'.$get_row['name']?>
    </td>
    <td>
    <?echo $get_row['description']?>
    </td>
    <td>
    <?echo '&pound'.number_format($get_row['price'],2).'<br><br> <a href="cart.php?add='.$get_row['id'].'">Add</a></p>';?>
    </td>
    </tr>
<?
 }
?>
</table></center>
<?
```

instead of your while loop :

```
while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {?>
    <center>
    <table border=2 width=90% cellspacing=5 cellpadding=10 bgcolor=cyan cols=2>

    ..............

    </table></center>

<?}
```

I hope it helps.

## edit

Please consider changing from `mysql` PHP functions to `mysqli` or `PDO` since `mysql` family is marked as deprecated by PHP team.
Here you can find more about:  **[mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)** and **[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)**.

Answer (score -1):

I imagine your table will have a "type" field that contains "starter", "main" or "dessert". If it doesn't then I don't know how you will distinguish between the products.

I would get the starters, mains and desserts separately like this first:

```
$starters = mysql_query('SELECT id, name, description, price FROM products WHERE quantity > 0 AND type = 'starter' ORDER BY id DESC');

$mains = mysql_query('SELECT id, name, description, price FROM products WHERE quantity > 0 AND type = 'main' ORDER BY id DESC');

$desserts = mysql_query('SELECT id, name, description, price FROM products WHERE quantity > 0 AND type = 'dessert' ORDER BY id DESC');
```

Then in your function loop over each group separately with the table headers at the top only.

```
function products() {
    $get = mysql_query('SELECT id, name, description, price FROM products WHERE quantity > 0 ORDER BY id DESC');
    if (mysql_num_rows($get) == 0) {
        echo "There are no products to display.";
    }
    else {
    echo <<<HERE
<center>
        <table border=2 width=90% cellspacing=5 cellpadding=10 bgcolor=cyan cols=2>
        <th>View</th>
        <th>Dish</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Item Price</th>
        <tr>
HERE;

    while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($starters)) {?>

        <td>    
        <a href="ice.png"</a>
        </td>
        <td>
        <?echo '<p>'.$get_row['name']?>
        </td>
        <td>
        <?echo $get_row['description']?>
        </td>
        <td>
        <?echo '&pound'.number_format($get_row['price'],2).'<br><br> <a href="cart.php?add='.$get_row['id'].'">Add</a></p>';?>
        </td>
        </tr>


    <?} 

    while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($mains)) {?>

        <td>    
        <a href="ice.png"</a>
        </td>
        <td>
        <?echo '<p>'.$get_row['name']?>
        </td>
        <td>
        <?echo $get_row['description']?>
        </td>
        <td>
        <?echo '&pound'.number_format($get_row['price'],2).'<br><br> <a href="cart.php?add='.$get_row['id'].'">Add</a></p>';?>
        </td>
        </tr>


    <?} 

    while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($desserts)) {?>

        <td>    
        <a href="ice.png"</a>
        </td>
        <td>
        <?echo '<p>'.$get_row['name']?>
        </td>
        <td>
        <?echo $get_row['description']?>
        </td>
        <td>
        <?echo '&pound'.number_format($get_row['price'],2).'<br><br> <a href="cart.php?add='.$get_row['id'].'">Add</a></p>';?>
        </td>
        </tr>


    <?} 
echo "</table></center>";
}
```

This could be refactored but I think it's the sort of thing you are looking for.